# Capybara with Poltergeist (PhantomJS) not rendering page and fonts correctly

Tags: fonts, rendering, screenshot, phantomjs, poltergeist

The setup in `spec_helper.rb` is:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, { js_errors: true }) 
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

Then in the `scenario` I have:

```
save_screenshot('tmp/screenshot.png', :full => true)
```

One more thing. The fonts aren't good. I'm using Google font, but it's not rendered correctly only in Poltergeist.

```
%link{href: "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}
```

As a result, whole page looks broken. Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, there's no support for Google fonts right now.
Google fonts are in .woff format. You need to download the desired font, and then it should work.

[More info](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/issues/410).